# Is there a limit to how many times Twice can copy himself?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In chapter 230 of the manga,

> Twice multiplied himself thousands of times

Is there a limit to how many times Twice can copy himself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no theoretical limit, but the quirk isn't insanely overpowered due to well designed limits.

This was the description of his quirk 'Double' at the start of Chapter 230,

[image]

As per the [wiki page](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Double): (emphasis mine)

> Jin has a limit of creating only two clones at a time. However, because Jin is able to copy himself and his copies also have access to Double, he is **theoretically capable of producing infinite replicas of himself** by letting his clones duplicate themselves further. This gives Jin the manpower to realize a large task easily or several smaller ones at once, provided that his clones cooperate with him. Tomoyasu Chikazoku claims that Double can replicate even dead people.

From what I see there are 2 limitations to the quirk:

1. The durability of the clones. Twice mentions that an injury equivalent to a broken bone will dissolve a clone, while the second copy is usually weaker.
2. The clones are autonomous. He can't really control them, only create them and detect their deaths. This *possibly* prevents him from cloning any heroes or even villains who are much more powerful than himself. After all, he was deeply traumatized by his own clones almost killing him, and even after the current developments, I doubt he will be using the "Infinite Doubles" move as anything but a last resort.

Also an interesting observation, while I couldn't find any confirmation for it. The infinite limit seems to indicate that all of his clones (even those created by the clones) will have durability proportional to the original. I initially thought it would be based on the clone which uses the ability, in which case the compounded penalties would force a mathematical limit after which the clones are way too easy to kill.